# Latex Fraction Paranthesis/Bracket Format

Tags: fractions

How would I get the Paranthesis/Bracket to go around the entire fraction, instead of appearing at the height of a normal one

Comment: Prentice? Do you mean parenthesis? `\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)` or `\Bigl(\frac{a}{b}\Bigr)`

Comment: Well same principle ... `\left[\frac{a}{b}\right]` or `\Bigl[\frac{a}{b}\Bigr]`. There's `\bigl`, `\Bigl`, `\biggl` and `\Biggl` (and obviously `\bigr` etc.), in increasing order of size. You can use these to manually select bracket sizes. The `\left` and `\right` options automatically scale to enclose everything but sometimes you get very bad spacing, for example if your numerator is taller than your denominator, there will be a big gap between the bottom of the fraction and the bottom of the brackets

Comment: See, for example, [this recent question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295961/how-do-i-fix-the-vertical-alignment-of-the-bracketed-part-of-this-equation/297030)