# how to increase Bracket size in Variance formula?

Tags: formatting, inline, displaystyle

I want to increase the size of the bracket to display more nicely the output, but I didn't find out how.

```
$$s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}[\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -
\frac{(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i)^2}{n}]$$
```

Here is the image that I obtain :

[image]

And here is the output that I want. (PS.  I want the sum with i=1 below and n above, in the image the output is not 100% what I want), I took that from a word document)

[image]

To test the output, I use the sample file : sample-dynamic-2.html  from MathJax.

UPDATED :

I changed the formula to :

```
$$s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\Biggl[\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \frac{(\su\limits_{i=1}^n x_i)^2}{n}\Biggr]$$
```

I obtain this instead :

[image]

Comment: See comments on [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297388/latex-fraction-paranthesis-bracket-format) from a couple of days ago. In another news, `$$ ... $$` should be replaced by `\[ ... \]` in LaTeX

Comment: Well, again, you would have to add `\biggl( ... \biggr)` around the summation in the fraction to adjust those brackets (although here you could probably use `\left( \right)` without ill effect.

Comment: *However* I would really advise against using limits in the numerator of a fraction, it makes for a very unbalanced appearance. You also don't need to use `\limits` at all with the first summation.

Comment: I think `\left[ ... \right]` will produce the desired results...

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers.  That helped me to understand LaTeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot comment (too less reputation), because this is only an answer on top of the answer of egreg.

The best way to obtain proper sized brackets are left/right brackets, which resize depending on the size of the formula "in between" them. Therefore one should extend the answer of egreg to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[% the ugly
    s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\biggl[\,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \frac{\Bigl(\,\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\Bigr)^{\!2}}{n} \biggr]
\]
\[% the bad
    s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\biggl[\,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \frac{\bigl(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\bigr)^2}{n}\biggr]
\]
\[% the good
    s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\biggl[\,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \frac{1}{n}\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\biggr)^{\!2}\,\biggr]
\]
\[% the better
    s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^{\!2} \right]
\]
\[% the better but ugly
    s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \frac{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^{2}}{n} \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

By the left/right brackets it is also no problem to let the sum in the numerator, although (as the others) I would strongly recommend to omit this.

[image: Output of given code with pdflatex]

Further I would recommend to define somthing like

```
\renewcommand*{brr}[1]{\left(#1\right)} % bracket round
\renewcommand*{brs}[1]{\left[#1\right]} % bracket square
\renewcommand*{brc}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}} % bracket curly
```

To be able to adjust spacings through your whole document (compare the `\,` after the opening square bracket in examples 1-3 and the versions without (4 and 5).

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers.  That helped me to understand LaTeX.  At the end, I use the equation with the syntax \left, \right

Answer (score 2):

I can propose three ways of typesetting the formula, in order of preference (see the comments in the code):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[% the ugly
s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\biggl[\,
  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -
    \frac{\Bigl(\,\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\Bigr)^{\!2}}{n}
  \biggr]
\]
\[% the bad
s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\biggl[\,
  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -
    \frac{\bigl(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\bigr)^2}{n}
  \biggr]
\]
\[% the good
s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\biggl[\,
  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -
    \frac{1}{n}\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\biggr)^{\!2}
  \,\biggr]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503) for `$$`; in a normal document, there shouldn't be consecutive display environments, but here it's just as way of example.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers.  That helped me to understand LaTeX.